# Rails plugin for US states and cities

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We need a Rails plugin for US states and cities. Please see if we can get that.

Comment: It would seem that instead of a plugin, you're looking for a data set to add to your database, no?

Comment: That would do... Where can I find that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would help: http://github.com/bcardarella/decoder

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, the National Weather Service produces such a data source:
http://www.weather.gov/geodata/catalog/national/html/cities.htm

Answer (score 2):

CityState gem: https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state

```
CS.states(:us)
# => {:AK=>"Alaska", :AL=>"Alabama", :AR=>"Arkansas", :AZ=>"Arizona", :CA=>"California", :CO=>"Colorado", :CT=>"Connecticut", :DC=>"District of Columbia", :DE=>"Delaware", :FL=>"Florida", :GA=>"Georgia", :HI=>"Hawaii", :IA=>"Iowa", :ID=>"Idaho", :IL=>"Illinois", :IN=>"Indiana", :KS=>"Kansas", :KY=>"Kentucky", :LA=>"Louisiana", :MA=>"Massachusetts", :MD=>"Maryland", :ME=>"Maine", :MI=>"Michigan", :MN=>"Minnesota", :MO=>"Missouri", :MS=>"Mississippi", :MT=>"Montana", :NC=>"North Carolina", :ND=>"North Dakota", :NE=>"Nebraska", :NH=>"New Hampshire", :NJ=>"New Jersey", :NM=>"New Mexico", :NV=>"Nevada", :NY=>"New York", :OH=>"Ohio", :OK=>"Oklahoma", :OR=>"Oregon", :PA=>"Pennsylvania", :RI=>"Rhode Island", :SC=>"South Carolina", :SD=>"South Dakota", :TN=>"Tennessee", :TX=>"Texas", :UT=>"Utah", :VA=>"Virginia", :VT=>"Vermont", :WA=>"Washington", :WI=>"Wisconsin", :WV=>"West Virginia", :WY=>"Wyoming"} 

CS.cities(:ak, :us)
# => ["Adak", "Akhiok", "Akiachak", "Akiak", "Akutan", "Alakanuk", "Ambler", "Anchor Point", "Anchorage", "Angoon", "Atqasuk", "Barrow", "Bell Island Hot Springs", "Bethel", "Big Lake", "Buckland", "Chefornak", "Chevak", "Chicken", "Chugiak", "Coffman Cove", "Cooper Landing", "Copper Center", "Cordova", "Craig", "Deltana", "Dillingham", "Douglas", "Dutch Harbor", "Eagle River", "Eielson Air Force Base", "Fairbanks", "Fairbanks North Star Borough", "Fort Greely", "Fort Richardson", "Galena", "Girdwood", "Goodnews Bay", "Haines", "Homer", "Hooper Bay", "Juneau", "Kake", "Kaktovik", "Kalskag", "Kenai", "Ketchikan", "Kiana", "King Cove", "King Salmon", "Kipnuk", "Klawock", "Kodiak", "Kongiganak", "Kotlik", "Koyuk", "Kwethluk", "Levelock", "Manokotak", "May Creek", "Mekoryuk", "Metlakatla", "Mountain Village", "Nabesna", "Naknek", "Nazan Village", "Nenana", "New Stuyahok", "Nikiski", "Ninilchik", "Noatak", "Nome", "Nondalton", "Noorvik", "North Pole", "Northway", "Old Kotzebue", "Palmer", "Pedro Bay", "Petersburg", "Pilot Station", "Point Hope", "Point Lay", "Prudhoe Bay", "Russian Mission", "Sand Point", "Scammon Bay", "Selawik", "Seward", "Shungnak", "Sitka", "Skaguay", "Soldotna", "Stebbins", "Sterling", "Sutton", "Talkeetna", "Teller", "Thorne Bay", "Togiak", "Tok", "Toksook Bay", "Tuntutuliak", "Two Rivers", "Unalakleet", "Unalaska", "Valdez", "Wainwright", "Wasilla"]
```

It works with all countries over the world. Also, it uses the MaxMind database so its continuously updated (with command `CS.update`)

Answer (score 0):

I just took the data from the NWS and created a Rails [plugin called geoinfo](http://github.com/mettadore/geoinfo) hosted on Github. At this point, it's still a quick hack, but contains all the NWS data in the lib/db folder if you don't want to use it as a plugin. Hope this helps.